# Why doesn't Regex work on a PreviewKeyDown?

Tags: c#, regex

This is currently my code to prevent all characters but `alphanumeric`. however this doesn't work.

```
private void LoginUsername_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"))
        {
           e.Handled = true;    // BreakPoint 'doesn't break'
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;   // BreakPoint 'breaks'
        }
    }
```

Using `KeyDown Event` > Doesn't work.

Using `TextChange Event` > works more than fine~!

I even tried `BreakPoint` in `PreviewKeyDown` but it never hits the `e.Handle`~!

Am i missing something?

Comment: have you tried to run Regex.isMatch() from the Immediate window to see the result? Edit: I think I know what happens. I'll add a reply.

Comment: What is `e.Key.ToString()`? I suspect it is `Space` and therefor will not be matched by the regex (because it only contains alphanumeric chars). Testing is easy, just put your breakpoint on the `if` itself, not the conditionally executed code block. When the breakpoint is hit, you can inspect the values of `e.Key`, `e.Key.ToString()` as well as evaluate `Regex.IsMatch`. Should get you an answer in no-time

Comment: I don't think this is the problem since it works on `TextChange` but ill check that.

Comment: @Hossam `TextChange` gives you the actual text; in this case you are getting an enumeration value, which when you call `.ToString()` will give you values like `Space`, `Tab`, *etc.*

Comment: `Regex` returns the values correctly `true` when match a non-alph, `false` when doesn't!

Comment: As i just said the `Regex` i'm using retruns the right values `true`, `false` while the `If Statement` should execute when `true` but it doesn't. However, i was using this before and it was no problem.

Comment: @Hossam: it obviously isn't returning the value you think it does. Have you tried to set a breakpoint and inspect the actual values as I suggested?

Comment: Aha yes, you're right it doesn't, i just didn't understand you well enough since i'm not a native english :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would cast `e.Key` to `int` and check whether the numeric value matches the sign you allow instead of using `ToString()` method

Answer (score 1):

When you press a non-character key like Space or Shift or Control or everything that's not just 1 single character, e.Key returns a special Enum value, which when done ToString() becomes (if you press Space) "Space". `Regex.IsMatch(string, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]")` Checks: "Is this a non-alphanumeric character". However, because you don't include ^ and $ in your regex to indicate you need to match the entire string, not just a substring, it basically checks "Are all of the characters non-alphanumeric?" Because "Space" has alphanumeric characters, it does not find a match.

Try using the Regex `@"^[^a-zA-Z0-9]$"`, because this compares for the entire string to be a non-alphanumeric character, not just individual characters.

And yes, as tDragon suggests, comparing against the intvalue of the string can be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that using the `TextInput` event is much less complicating than the `KeyDown`

So here's my solution for others to benefit:

```
private async void LoginUsername_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Char keyChar = (Char)System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(e.Text)[0];

        if (Regex.IsMatch(keyChar.ToString(), @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```